# How to detect end of file transfer in c# tcplistener

Tags: c#, tcp, file-transfer, tcplistener

I want to listen for a file send to me. In order to do this I wrote the following code:

```
private void Listen()
{
    IPAddress localip = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 127,0,0,1 });
    Console.WriteLine("now listing, IP: " + localip);
    var listener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(localip, 5678));
    listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        using (var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
        using (var stream = client.GetStream())
        using (var output = File.Create("result.data"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected. Starting to receive the file");


            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("done receiving message");


        }

    }
}
```

}

Now this works fine but once I have received the file the code hangs on the line                  `while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)` rather than continue to the line `Console.WriteLine("done receiving message");`. So rather than detecting that it's reading 0 bytes (and thus no longer satisfying the conditions of the while loop) it instead hangs. When I try to inspect it in a debugger it gives me the error

```
stream.DataAvailable
Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on the top of the call stack.
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: let client send the header with file size(first 4 or 8 bytes) then read until you recive whole file (bytes readed == size)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the client.

Comment: It seems unlikely that whatever is sending you the file is just dumping it over the wire without some kind of encapsulating protocol, is that really the case?

Comment: *Unfortunately I have no control over the client* so play with ReceiveTimeout of accepted TcpClient

Comment: Are you sure it´s "receiving zero bytes"? If it returns with zero bytes read it would mean that the peer had gracefully closed the connection, which might not be the case.